# Function for list of tuples/elements in Python Hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

In my unit tests I use the same combination of strategies fairly often:

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st

@given(st.text(), st.integers(), st.floats())
def test_stuff(text, integer, float):
    ...
```

I was hoping I could extract that combination like so:

```
def combo():
    return st.tuples(st.text(), st.integers(), st.floats())
```

So that I could use it in this shorter way:

```
@given(combo())
def test_stuff(text, integer, float):
    ...
```

However, then I get `fixture 'text' not found`. Is there a way to achieve what I want with Hypothesis?

Comment: just make `def test_stuff(args)` with `@given(combo())` then in the test do `text, integer, float = args`

Answer (score 0):

Your specific idea is not supported, because there must always be a one-to-one correspondence between arguments to @given() and to the test function.

However, there are a couple of workarounds you could use:

- as juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, you could unpack your arguments within the test function
- alternatively, you could have a global dictionary of `common = {"text": ..., "integer": ..., etc}` and then unpack it with `@given(**common)`